# Putting a title on a Feynman diagram with feynmp

Tags: feynmf

I would like to put an overall title for a FeynMP diagram, as it is going to be put in a figure side by side with many other Feynman diagrams. I would like it to look something like this:[image: FeynMP diagram with a title]

The option to put it either top or bottom would be also welcome. The source without the title is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\unitlength = 1mm
%lb - left bottom
%rt - right top
\begin{fmffile}{gluon}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(30,30)
  \fmfleft{lb,lt}
  \fmflabel{Left bottom}{lb}
  \fmflabel{Right bottom}{rb}
  \fmfright{rb,rt}
  \fmflabel{Right top}{rt}
  \fmflabel{Left top}{lt}
  \fmf{fermion}{lb,v1}
  \fmf{fermion}{v1,rt}
  \fmf{dashes_arrow}{rb,v1}
  \fmf{fermion}{v1,lt}
  \fmfdot{v1}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\write18{mpost gluon}
\end{document}
```

Any information will be appreciated!

Comment: This answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174654/labeling-several-out-incoming-lines-collectively-in-feynmp/174667#174667 shows how to put a feynmf result into a box, thereby allowing you to place text adjacent (or above) it in a manner of your choosing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There's no need of doing `\write18{mpost gluon}`, for `feynmp` already takes care of it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys!

egreg: I thought so too, but if I remove it, does not work for me any more. gluon.mp is generated, but not mposted.

Steven B. Segletes: I cannot use this. Two reasons: the labels ("Left bottom", etc.) are outside the box, and 
otherwise how do I center my title relative to the diagram?

As a general remark, possibly related to egreg's comment, I prefer compiling the figures to PDFs and them embeddings the PDF into my paper. Is that not how you guys do it?

Thanks again in any case!

Answer (score 3):

I've come up with two ways to solve the problem:

1) Add the title to the tex file which generates the diagram. The advantage is that the title is the same size as the labels on the diagram. Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\unitlength = 1mm
%lb - left bottom
%rt - right top
%
\begin{center}
TITLE
\vspace{3ex} %space that is 3 'x' letters high
\end{center}
%
\begin{fmffile}{gluon}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(30,30)
  \fmfleft{lb,lt}
  \fmflabel{Left bottom}{lb}
  \fmflabel{Right bottom}{rb}
  \fmfright{rb,rt}
  \fmflabel{Right top}{rt}
  \fmflabel{Left top}{lt}
  \fmf{fermion}{lb,v1}
  \fmf{fermion}{v1,rt}
  \fmf{dashes_arrow}{rb,v1}
  \fmf{fermion}{v1,lt}
  \fmfdot{v1}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\write18{mpost gluon}
\end{document}
```

2) After generating the PDFs, put them into subfigures, as described in the [wikibooks latex tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats).

Thanks again to egreg and Steven B. Segletes!