# How to draw disconnected Feynman diagrams with the feynMF package?

Tags: diagrams, feynmf

I just discovered the [`feynMF` package](http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/feynmf/fmfman.pdf), a really neat tool for drawing Feynman diagrams.

I went ahead and drew a few diagrams which I'll include here just to set the right spirit for this question. I produced this

[image]

with this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmf}

\begin{document}
$\begin{fmffile}{Diagram}
\begin{fmffile}{Diagram}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(40,15)
   \fmfpen{thin}
   \fmfleft{i}
   \fmfright{o}
   \fmf{plain}{i,o}
   \fmfdot{i,o}
   \fmfv{l.a=-90,l=$x$}{i}
   \fmfv{l.a=-90,l=$y$}{o}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\quad + \quad
\begin{fmfgraph*}(40,15)
   \fmfpen{thin}
   \fmfleft{i}
   \fmfright{o}
   \fmf{plain}{i,v,v,o}
   \fmfdot{i,o,v}
   \fmfv{l.a=-90,l=$x$}{i}
   \fmfv{l.a=-90,l=$y$}{o}
   \fmfv{l.a=-90,l=$z$}{v}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\quad + \quad
\begin{fmfgraph*}(40,15)
   \fmfpen{thin}
   \fmfleft{i}
   \fmfright{o}
   \fmf{plain}{i,v1,v2,o}
   \fmf{plain,left,tension=0.05}{v1,v2,v1}
   \fmfdot{i,o,v1,v2}
   \fmfv{l.a=-90,l=$x$}{i}
   \fmfv{l.a=-90,l=$y$}{o}
   \fmfv{l.a=-90}{v1,v2}
   \fmflabel{$z_{1}$}{v1}
   \fmflabel{$z_{2}$}{v2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\quad + \enskip \dots
\end{fmffile}
\end{fmffile}$

\end{document}
```

Then I wanted to draw a few disconnected diagrams. This is where I got stuck. I'm trying to get this

[image]

Not very pretty I admit, but you get the idea, I hope. However, everything I tried so far did not compile. Is anybody sufficiently familiar with feynMF that could help me out here?

Comment: not on topic. But do you know `feynmp-auto`? It issues the metapost run automatically so you do not have to do it yourself. No intermediate runs of metafont oder metapost anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure if the point is to draw the shapes you mention, or to have the ability to draw the images inline with text and such.  If it is the latter, I had done this a while back: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174654/labeling-several-out-incoming-lines-collectively-in-feynmp/174667#174667, which uses `feynmp-auto`.

Comment: @MaxNoe Maybe you're right. However, I am trying to achieve a well-defined purpose with a specific package. So any answer should still be useful to others who run into similar problems. If no answers appear in the next two days, I'll delete this question.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The point is the former. How to draw the shapes in the second image?

Comment: I did not mean your question. I meant my comment.

Comment: @MaxNoe I see. I learned about the package `feynmp-auto` yesterday. While writing this question Stackexchange suggested similar questions some of which I looked at. In [this thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181427/feynman-diagrams-with-feynmf-and-feynmp?rq=1), egreg recommended the use of `feynmp-auto` over `feynmf`. However, since I am using ShareLaTeX most of the time, this ordeal of compiling several times does not affect me. I'll still use `feynmp-auto` from now on since it's supposed to be easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I contacted Thorsten Ohl, the creator of `feynMF`, and asked him if disconnected diagrams are possible with his package. His honest reply read

> ... it needs more tricks than I like, but it's possible.

In my opinion, his solution looks really good:

[image]

To reproduce or modify this output, use the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{\jobname-pics}
\begin{center}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(30,30)
     \fmfpen{thin}
     \fmftop{t}
     \fmfbottom{b}
     \fmf{phantom}{t,v1,b}
     \fmffreeze
     \fmfi{plain}{vloc(__v1){(1,1)}..vloc(__t)..{(1,-1)}vloc(__v1)}
     \fmfi{plain}{vloc(__v1){(-1,-1)}..vloc(__b)..{(-1,1)}vloc(__v1)}
     \fmfdot{v1}
     \fmfv{l=$z_1$,l.angle=180,l.dist=3thick}{v1}
  \end{fmfgraph*}\qquad
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(30,45)
     \fmfpen{thin}
     \fmftop{t}
     \fmfbottom{b}
     \fmf{phantom}{t,v1,v2,b}
     \fmffreeze
     \fmfi{plain}{vloc(__v1){(1,1)}..vloc(__t)..{(1,-1)}vloc(__v1)}
     \fmfi{plain}{vloc(__v2){(-1,-1)}..vloc(__b)..{(-1,1)}vloc(__v2)}
     \fmfi{plain}{vloc(__v1){(1.5,-1)}..{(-1.5,-1)}vloc(__v2)}
     \fmfi{plain}{vloc(__v2){(-1.5,1)}..{(1.5,1)}vloc(__v1)}
     \fmfdot{v1,v2}
     \fmfv{l=$z_1$,l.angle=180,l.dist=3thick}{v1}
     \fmfv{l=$z_2$,l.angle=180,l.dist=3thick}{v2}
  \end{fmfgraph*}\qquad
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(30,60)
     \fmfpen{thin}
     \fmftop{t}
     \fmfbottom{b}
     \fmf{phantom}{t,v1,v2,v3,b}
     \fmffreeze
     \fmfi{plain}{vloc(__v1){(1,1)}..vloc(__t)..{(1,-1)}vloc(__v1)}
     \fmfi{plain}{vloc(__v3){(-1,-1)}..vloc(__b)..{(-1,1)}vloc(__v3)}
     \fmfi{plain}{vloc(__v1){(1.5,-1)}..{(-1.5,-1)}vloc(__v2)}
     \fmfi{plain}{vloc(__v2){(1.5,-1)}..{(-1.5,-1)}vloc(__v3)}
     \fmfi{plain}{vloc(__v3){(-1.5,1)}..{(1.5,1)}vloc(__v2)}
     \fmfi{plain}{vloc(__v2){(-1.5,1)}..{(1.5,1)}vloc(__v1)}
     \fmfdot{v1,v2,v3}
     \fmfv{l=$z_1$,l.angle=180,l.dist=3thick}{v1}
     \fmfv{l=$z_2$,l.angle=180,l.dist=3thick}{v2}
     \fmfv{l=$z_3$,l.angle=180,l.dist=3thick}{v3}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(30,50)
     \fmfpen{thin}
     \fmftop{t}
     \fmfbottom{b}
     \fmf{phantom}{t,v1,dummy1,dummy2,v2,b}
     \fmffreeze
     \fmfi{plain}{vloc(__v1){(1,-1)}..{(-1,-1)}vloc(__v2)}
     \fmfi{plain}{vloc(__v2){(-1,1)}..{(1,1)}vloc(__v1)}
     \fmfi{plain}{vloc(__v1){(1,-3)}..{(-1,-3)}vloc(__v2)}
     \fmfi{plain}{vloc(__v2){(-1,3)}..{(1,3)}vloc(__v1)}
     \fmfdot{v1,v2}
     \fmfv{l=$z_1$,l.angle=90,l.dist=3thick}{v1}
     \fmfv{l=$z_2$,l.angle=-90,l.dist=3thick}{v2}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{center}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```